# Why can't I create PHP project using Eclipse Juno?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have Eclipse Juno installed in Fedora 17 from the standard Fedora repositories.
I've added PDT from the Eclipse repository using the help->install new software interface.

However, when I go to create a new project I don't get the option to create a PHP project, only plain 'General' projects.

Why doesn't Eclipse let me create a PHP project and how can I fix this?

Comment: Could you confirm whether you successfully installed PDT or not? You can check it via 'Help' - 'About Eclipse SDK'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I closed Eclipse and deleted ~/.eclipse/*, restarted Eclipse and the PHP plugins (and others) seem to have woken up.

Still don't know what was causing it, but I'm in a place I can get work done now at least!

Comment: It was useful to know that PDT works on Eclipse Juno. This is the link to the installation guide: http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation_3.1.x